# How to loop a checkedlistbox item and move down the list in order with delphi

Tags: delphi

I am trying to do a simple playlist for a radio station.  I have most of it working, where it plays a jingle every five tracks, but the issue I am having is I have no idea how to play each checked item (jingle) in the list one after the other.

Step by step actions:

1. I would add a jingle or jingles to list;

   ```
   JvPlayList.Items.AddStrings(OpenDialog1.Files);
   ```
2. I would then select each jingle I would want to play in order (screen shot);

   [image]
3. Then once a jingle has finished playing, it would move on to the next checked jingle in the list, and so on;

I have no real code for this at this time, as its just in my mind on how I would like it to work.  So I'm just wondering if its possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.  You just need a variable to keep track of the current index that is being played.

Starting at index 0, loop through the `TCheckListBox.Checked[]` property until it returns true (or you reach the end of the list).  If found, save the index and play the corresponding file in the `TCheckListBox.Items[index]` property value.

When the file is done playing, loop through the list again, starting at the next index.

Repeat as needed.

For example:

```
private
  FCurrentIndex: Integer;
  function StartNextPlayListItem: Boolean;

...

procedure TMyForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FCurrentIndex := -1;
end;

function TMyForm.StartNextPlayListItem: Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
  for I := FCurrentIndex+1 to CheckListBox1.Items.Count-1 do
  begin
    if CheckListBox1.Checked[I] then
    begin
      FCurrentIndex := I;
      // start playing CheckListBox1.Items[I]...
      Result := True;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TMyForm.SomeStartEvent;
begin
  StartNextPlayListItem;
end;

procedure TMyForm.DonePlayingAFile;
begin
  StartNextPlayListItem;
end;
```

Comment: ok see the problem I have is the way I detect when a track is finished it uses a timer event and checks progress bar for 100% then it will fire up the next track or jingle but if I use function the timer will fill the FCurrentIndex fast so it never matchs so am wondering if there a better way to know when the track has finished other then using timer

if (scbTrackBar.PartsComplete = BASS_ChannelGetLength(chan, BASS_POS_BYTE)) then // play next track

Comment: I don't see the problem. Regardless of HOW you detect the end of playback (and you can use `BASS_ChannelSetSync()` to assign a `BASS_SYNC_END` callback to detect end of playback), the above code would work fine. Once you reach 100%, you stop and close the current file, find the next file, and open and play it.  What is the actual problem? "*the timer will fill the FCurrentIndex fast so it never matchs*" makes no sense, as you wouldn't be searching for the next index until you are ready for it to begin with.